# Application not responding, process missing

Tags: macos, dock

I have an odd issue. Sometimes it happens that application (happens almost always to NetBeans) is stuck in the dock with "Not Responding" - I can't open it, if I select "Force quit" id doesn't do anything (both from dock and from "Force quit" window.

The most annoying thing - there is no associated process that I could kill!

The only way to start application again is to restart the whole osx, which is PITA.

How can I force-force-quit of such application?

Comment: Does it still show up in Activity Monitor or if you run `ps aux` in Terminal?

Comment: as I said - there is no associated process - neither in activity monitor nor as a result of ps aux (neither for netbeans, java nor bash - I've read it may also be listed).